# How to download images in nested tags from a website

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to download all images in *img* tag, which are nested in something like this:

```
<div id="onlive">
  <div>
    <section class="class1">
      <ul class=="class2">
        <li>
          <div class="class3">
            <div class="class4 class4-001" video_id="001">
              <div class="class5">
                <img src="https://...">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="class3">
            <div class="class4 class4-002" video_id="002">
              <div class="class5">
                <img src="https://...">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example, there should be 5 images to be downloaded and save in "images" directory. Also, I want to use the "video-id" as the name of each image.

Here is my code. It has no errors but does not get any image:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import logging
import urllib.request

url = "https://www...com/onlive" 
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

links = []
for img in soup.find_all('img'):
    link = img.get('src')
    links.append(link)

for i in range(len(links)):
    filename = 'images/img{}.jpg'.format(i)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(links[i], filename)
```

Comment: have you tried printing `links` to see if it is not empty?

Comment: @AndreaOggioni Yes, I already tried, and it gets nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Based strictly on the sample html in the question, this should work on the relevant portion of the code:

```
videos = """your html above, fixed""" #the html you have there is malformed
soup = bs(videos,'lxml')
targets = soup.select('div[class*="class4"]')
for target in targets:
  i= target.attrs['video_id']
  link = target.select_one('img').attrs['src']
  filename = f'images/img{i}.jpg'
  print(filename,link)
```

Output:

```
images/img001.jpg https://...
images/img002.jpg https://...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yet, I forgot to add one thing. `<div class="class4-001" video_id="001"> and <div class="class4-002" video_id="002">`. What should I do in this case since they have different class names? I updated my question, please check.

Comment: I tried this code, but it did not work. I did not get any images. What should I do with the url? Technically, I want to download the profile pic of each video.

Comment: @belle - I only focused on the html in your question. Check the url - if it's dynamically loaded, requests won't be able to process it and you'll have to use something like selenium.